# I'm not getting loops to take a new value after each loop?

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve a problem where I try to get my loop to take a new value after every loop. The program is suppose to fine me my Interest payment,principal payment an current balance, doing so my interest is suppose to be less an lesser every time I loop but its only looping the first answer over an over

Here is the output which the first answer is correct but the other three is

```
    Enter Loan Amount:500
    Enter Annual Interest:50
    Total payment:4
    Enter Loan Length :1
    Interest PaymentPrincipal PaymentCurrent Balance
    Interest Payment Principal Payment Current Balance 62.5
    62.5
    62.5
    62.5
```

It supposed to be 12.5% of the balance after the first payment.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //variabled decleared
        double rate;
        double payment;
        int amt = 1;
       //input
       System.out.print("Enter Loan Amount:");
        double principal = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Annual Interest:");
        double interest = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Total payment:");//12=monthly,4= quartely,2=semi-annually and 1=annually
        double period = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Loan Length :");
        int length = input.nextInt();

        //proces
        rate = interest / 100;
        double period_rate = rate / period;
          double n = period * length;
        payment = (principal*Math.pow((1+period_rate),n))/n;





        System.out.printf("\n"+"Interest Payment"+"     Principal Payment       "+"         Current Balance     ");

        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        double principal_payment=0;
        double current_balance;
        double payment_interest;

        current_balance=(principal-principal_payment);
         payment_interest=(principal*period_rate);
        principal_payment=(payment-payment_interest);
        principal=current_balance;



         System.out.println(payment_interest+"");

         }
```

Comment: You don't have anything that's changing inside your loop.  You'll get the same result every time.

Comment: any assistance will do am new to programming thanks

Comment: What is principal here? Where is it declared?

Comment: You're calculating "current_balance", but it's a local inside the loop (declared inside the loop) and its value is not used anywhere.  What you basically need to do is to update "principal" inside the loop.

Comment: i have just edited it am suppose to find the interest for each payment after each loop

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the same value, to all the iterations of the for. Thats why you are getting always the same output.

If you want new value each time, either you prompt to the user to give you new input for each iteration. Or you do this before the for, store the input in arrays and work on them inside the loop.

Something like this pseudo code:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    //read principal from user input
    //read payment from user input
    // ect...
    payment_interest=(principal*period_rate);
    ...


}
```

You can see [here](http://cs.middlesexcc.edu/~schatz/csc211/handouts/readdouble.html) how to **Read a Double From the Keyboard**. Note that inside the loop you only need to ask the user for parameters that can vary.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about programming.  Get pencil and paper and work through the calculations for several months.  Then transfer those calculations to code.  You get ahead of yourself when you start coding before you understand what the problem is.

Comment: i know my calculations well because i do use pen an paper since am new am not  good with loops an am stuck on that area

Comment: Go back to the pen and paper and look at what you do.  Give a name to each value you calculate.  Note where you "loop" in the paper calculation, and which values you carry over from one iteration to the next.  There's nothing special about loops -- it's not a magical formula.  You just do what you'd do on paper.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the line:

principal=current_balance;

to:

principal = principal - principal_payment;

or change the loop to this:

```
double current_balance = principal;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        double principal_payment = 0;

        double payment_interest;

        //current_balance = (principal - principal_payment);
        payment_interest = (current_balance * period_rate);
        principal_payment = (payment - payment_interest);
        current_balance = current_balance - principal_payment;



        System.out.println(payment_interest + "");

    }
```

Comment: really, worked for me with your code:  Enter Loan Amount:500
Enter Annual Interest:50
Total payment:4
Enter Loan Length :1

Interest Payment     Principal Payment                Current Balance     62.5
45.284271240234375
25.916576385498047
4.127919673919678

Comment: one question though how do you get it to .2f